# How to implement a return statement when using a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, return

I am creating a method that returns the variable elt if it exists in an array.  If it does not exist in an array, I need to return null.

The issue is, I am checking for the variable elt in each item in the array using an if statement in a for-loop.  I do not think I can put a return statement at the end of the if statement in the for-loop, because each time it executes the if statement, the potential return value would be different.  I think this would make a new return value each time the for-loop was looped through.  To solve this, I created a boolean temp variable called exist.  If true, the method will return the variable elt.  If false, it will return null.  The code I am working with is below.

```
public T remove(T elt) {
        boolean exist;

        for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] == elt) {
                data[i] = null;
                size--;
                exist = true;
                System.out.println(exist);

                for (++i; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i-1] = data[i];
                }
            }
        }
        if (exist = true)
            return elt;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

My question is, is there a way to tuck the return statement in the method without using a temp variable?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to put a `return` in a `for` loop.  The method will finish and exit as soon as you return.

Comment: Note that your posted solution and the accepted solution differ in that yours removes all occurrences of `elt` in `data`, while the accepted solution only removes first encountered occurrence (and exits immediately). This might be good or bad depending on your method's contract.

Comment: @JiriTousek, thank you for pointing this out, you are absolutely right!  Though, it seems even my posted solution only removes the first encountered occurrence as well.  Can you give me a hint on how I can get it to remove all occurrences?  I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: @OmarN one problem I see is that when you delete an occurrence, you shift remaining items using the `i` varible, moving that one to the end of array in the process. Not a good practice by the way, I recommend you don't touch  the iteration variable unless necessary. Second thing, you shift all remaining items left, so so you'll skip testing / removing the former (i+1)-th element - that could be fixed by replacing the `if` with `while`.

Comment: Also I'll repeat what I wrote in mistake in comment to one of the answers - `if (exist = true)` will always evaluate to `true`, since `exist = true` is an assignment - you'll want `==` there instead of `=` if you're trying to make that code work.

Comment: @JiriTousek that makes sense.  Thank you for clarifying.  Btw, if I replace the `if` with `while`, I get an out of bounds exception.  This may have to do with other parts of the code though not posted in the OP.

Comment: Re OutOfBounds probably you'll need to make sure you didn't already remove the last element of the array and exit the while if you did.

Comment: @JiriTousek, thank you so much for your help.  I still cannot figure that portion out, so I hope you don't mind, but I posted another question to handle that specific portion of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a return statement almost anywhere.

To answer your question, you could put a return after your inner for loop like follows:

```
public T remove(T elt) {

    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] == elt) {
            data[i] = null;
            size--;
            System.out.println(exist);

            for (++i; i < data.length; i++) {
                data[i-1] = data[i];
            }

            return elt;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  To me, this looks like it will return both elt in the for-loop, and then return null once it exists the for-loop.  Isn't that how it would work?  In which case, I do not understand how it can return two things.

Comment: It cannot reach both return statements.  Once you reach a return statement, the code leaves the method and "returns" to the code that called it (aka: going back up the stack).  You can only have 1 return value.  Any code after a return will not be executed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use one extra variable . You can directly return from for loop. Instead of writing `exist = true` write `return elt`  and at the end 
instead of

```
if (exist = true)
            return elt;
        else
            return null;
```

just write `return null` so that if `elt` doesnt exist it will return null.

Comment: What about returning null if elt does not exist?  Will writing `return elt` return null automatically if elt does not exist?

Comment: @Jiri I copy pasted his code :). Anyways that code needs to be remvoed

Comment: @Rehman Errr...it was...it was a squirrel on my keyboard, definitely not me writing such a dumb comment. :)